# How do I access my Windows 10 file share?

Tags: dual-boot, samba, file-sharing, shared-folders

I am trying to access my Win10 shared drive from Ubuntu 18.04.  I know I need to edit the `smb.comf` file but I can't seem to do so.  I also know I need to open said file as root but I can't seem to find out how to do that.

Comment: Personally I guess that there is no need to edit '/etc/samba/smb.conf'. The default configuration should be ok. I cannot remember having edited that file once. If a folder is shared correctly, it should show up in '+ Other Locations' - 'Networks' in your File manager. - To edit a file that is owned by root: Open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) ('super'-key, search for terminal), then type 'sudo gedit' (confirm with your user password) which will open the text editor with administration rights. You can the open a file within the editor. You can also open the file with 'sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf'.

Comment: @minimec Your comment looks like an answer to me (perhaps you feel the question is unclear?) BTW, in Ubuntu versions before 19.10, we should not run `sudo gedit` but `sudo -H gedit` to avoid issues with configuration files in the user's home directory. From 19.10 onwards, `sudo` will reset HOME by default like other Linux distributions do so running `sudo gedit` will be the same as running `sudo -H gedit`.

Comment: You have "dual-boot" as one of your tags. Are you trying to access a Windows partition from your Linux install on the same machine? Or are you trying to access a separate Windows machine on the network?

Comment: No not a dual boot.  I am using a separate machine running Windows 10 setup with Storage Spaces as a would be server.  The Ubuntu machine that I am using for an HTPC can not even see the Windows Work space.  I am simply trying to file share over my network.  I remember doing this before where I had to make a small edit to my smb.conf file.  But I can't remember how to open the file as root.  Apologies if I have "miss tagged" this comment.  I could not find exactly what I was looking for and am very new to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I use "FileZilla Server for Windows" to share folders with other computers.

First, install "FileZilla Server for Windows";

Second, create a user in FileZilla Server and set shared folder;

Third, use FTP client on Ubuntu 18.04 to connect your server on windows.